# How to avoid repulsion between two bodies in box2d

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

When I create two dynamic bodies in box2d(cocos2dx), they repels each other and start to move in opposite directions. Which property I have to set to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create them on top of each other. It seems like you are not using the debug draw display to see what is really happening. I strongly recommend you use it.